# Facebook Developer Console - App Review

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am submitting an app for review on Facebook Developer Console. I have done everything required, however it is still telling me i need to 'test this permission in your app with any account listed in Roles before you can submit for review'.

I have logged into my app with the role i have provided. However this message still appears?

[image]

Comment: test the persmission by using the /me/photos endpoint in your app. if that does not remove the message, file a bug.